# Installing “atom-beautify@0.33.4” failed

Tags: atom-beautify

**when trying to install atom-beautify package, i have the following error.**

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...concat":"latest","@ty'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\HP.atom.apm_logs\2021-02-14T07_09_54_821Z-debug.log

**i made sure, the atom version is up to date, windows firewall is off, antivirus is off**

**pls help me to fix this issue. thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

delete the .apm folder inside the .atom folder
Thank you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you might be wondering where the apm folder is
you'll find it in the last options in the settings named open config folder with a link opening sign  tap on it wait for another page to load,right there you would see different folders.look for the apm folder and delete it.restart your atom app and try installing the beauty package.hope it works for you